# How can I filter CloudWatch logstreams to the logstreams of failed invocations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a Lambda function that has a success rate of over 99% (which is nice).

Occasionally there is an invocation which results in an error. I would like to view the log of that one invocation.

How can I find the cloudwatch logstream which contains the error invoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to apply filter patterns across the entire log group, which will query all logstreams.

If you're looking for a specific error phrase you can wrap it in double quotes such as "ERROR".

**From the console**

- Go to the CloudWatch service screen
- Click `Log groups`
- Click on your log group
- Click "Search All"
- Enter your pattern in the "Filter events" text box

**From the CLI**

Use the [filter-log-events](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html) function. An example is below

```
aws logs filter-log-events --start-time 1593967410000 --end-time 15945722100000 --log-group-name /aws/lambda/function-name --filter-pattern ERROR --output text
```

For examples of how to use more complex filter patterns take a look at the [Filter and Pattern Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) page.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. That is already a helpful start. Even though this gives me every line which has the word ERROR in it. There might be successful invokes which have (handled) errors

Comment: Hopefully you can find pattern that matches your logs specifically :)